# How to customize collapsed menu in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a navbar that I'm making with Bootstrap. I used a border underneath the hover menu elements, so you get the effect of a line appearing underneath the menu item as you hover over it. But I'm having a couple problems with the collapsed version of my menu.

1) The border won't go away in my vertical collapsed menu. It looks ridiculous.

2) The li elements look shitty on a tablet. They appear in-line still, and they bump up against the logo in the left corner of the page (which is an image that can't be seen in my codeply link).

I basically want to know how to customize JUST the collapsed menu, or the vertical menu, but I can't seem to find much on the subject. Here's a codeply, so you can see what I'm talking about.

http://www.codeply.com/go/TI1k70CPFm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues happen because you are triggering the toggle menu on `991px` and below using `css` where by default bootstrap toggle menu triggers during `767px` and below.

To fix that we need to set custom styles to work also during `991px` and below.

1) The border won't go away in my vertical collapsed menu. It looks ridiculous.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover::after,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus::after {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

2) The li elements look shitty on a tablet. They appear in-line still, and they bump up against the logo in the left corner of the page (which is an image that can't be seen in my codeply link).

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
    width: 100%;
    float: none !important;
  }

  .nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Putting together in media query `max 991px`

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
    width: 100%;
    float: none !important;
  }

  .nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover::after,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus::after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

[Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/nyppqenN6F)

Comment: My hero! Thanks dude.

Comment: @ThomasMcNish Cool! Glad to help.